# Access denied leading to mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, exception, dll

Been a lurker for a long time, first post. So just let me know what I need to do if I'm unclear, not enough information, etc.

System: Windows 7 VS2012 C#

Trying to just run the code from here, first method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546133.aspx

And it works as is for any file within my user directory, but not the user directory itself.
C:\Users\me\dir not C:\Users\me or up.
Getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException on C:\documents and settings

Looking around, most posts I found said to just

```
static void QueryDuplicates()
    {
      try
      { //Query for Duplicates }
      catch {//left blank}
    }
```

Which I think is insecure so I tired:

```
catch (Exceptions ex)
{
if {ex is System.UnauthorizedAccessException} {} 
else {Console.writeline(ex.message);}
}
```

which I guess is a little better :-(

That bypasses the original error but now I get 
"A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'occured in mscorlib.dll"
I find this odd because shouldn't this have been skipped over?

The best I've found is to make a manifest, but I'd rather not be skipping errors and then forcing a program to run as admin. Seems really insecure and a bandaid solution.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2007/04/19/embed-a-manifest-to-make-an-application-elevate-in-vista.aspx

The end result I'm looking for is to loop through a whole drive and find all the duplicate files. At least this is the first step in the program I'm writing. I'm looking for either a better solution than what I'm trying, a true fix for the issues, or anything to try.

Comment: The only solution which I'm aware is the link which you post.

Comment: Have you ever used it?